# How should I upgrade or combine sub-panels so I can add another one?

Tags: electrical

I'm building a poultry shed.  The building next to it has power going to it from the pole.  At the pole there are two breakers.  Then it goes into the old building where it looks like the two very old panels in there only have 120 coming from the pole each.

I put a panel in the new shed and buried 8-2, which I'm now thinking I may need to dig up and replace with #6.  The panel in the new shed is a six-spot 120/240 Homeline from Square D.

I have ran the hot to one bus and jumpered it to the other bus.  I have placed the neutral into the top bar and added a grounding bar attached directly to the panel.  I put in a grounding rod and ran a copper cable to the grounding bar in the panel.  I can go get pictures in a bit if needed.

**My questions are these:**

Am i wiring the panel in the new shed correctly considering the panel I'm coming from is only 120v?  The panel in the old building is probably from the 70's with the push button type breakers and no room available for another breaker.  The other leg of the 4 wire from the pole bypasses this breaker and goes to a breaker with a throw bar.  This just runs the lights in the old building.

Should/Do I need to replace the breaker panel in the old shed?  Should I combine both breaker boxes into a 240v panel?  There are 2 double pole breakers at the utility pole so I'm not sure if the 240 is separated there before going to the old shed.
The new shed has 5 outlets on 2 circuits and 2 lights on it's own circuit.  I'm seeing now that 8-2 only handles 40amps so I'm guessing I need to dig the 8-2 up and replace it with #6.

Do I need a main disconnect in the subpanel and if so how to I wire that in.

If pictures are needed I can get them this afternoon.

Thank you all for your time.

edited to add pics.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange.  Our traditional welcome ritual is to inundate you with followup questions.  How are the neutrals and grounds are arranged?  Is the new 8/2 cable is protected by a circuit breaker in any way? How did you place the wire on a breaker if the panel is full? Are these pushbutton panels Pushmatic?  Is it a new 40A breaker?

Comment: In the old shed the neutral and grounds are bonded.  I have them separated in the new panel.  I haven't hooked up the feed end of the new building at all yet.  I planned to just tie into the wires going to the breaker but after a bunch of reading realize this is wrong and not code so i've stopped.  I don't know the brand.  I'll see if i can find it.  Most of the writing has been worn off. I know deep down I need to fix the old barn first before I do anything else.  I'm confused by the 2 breakers on the utility pole. Thinking they each only feed 120v to the old shed.

Comment: Shoot us pix of the old panels starting at the pole.  Is there any breaker at the pole?  It's perfectly ok to hotwire subpanel 2 right off the lugs of subpanel 1, (we call that thru-lugging) if the breaker that supplies subpanel 1 is able to protect the wire to subpanel 2.

Comment: Did you install a ground rod for the chicken shed? I think you did the right thing isolating the neutral from the ground since there is a breaker on the pole. You mention reading code you think you did something wrong , if you only has 120v there is no problem tying the 2 busses together but the panel needs to have that label for future users. What is it you think you did wrong?

Comment: I think my main problem is I used the wrong size wire.  And the old breaker box in the old building.  I did add a ground pole pounded about 6 foot deep to the new chicken shed.  I'll add some pictures in a second.

Comment: What amp rating is the circuit you tapped the feeder from?

Comment: Can you get us photos of the labeling on the inside of the pole-box's door, or has that been lost to the mists of time?

Comment: I'll go look. I know that pole feeds the other building 240.

Comment: What are chickens going to do with electrical service?

Comment: heat lamps and an incubator

Comment: Pro-Tip™: Burying _oversized_ conduit means you don't have to redig to change out wire sizes. Would you please label the pictures to make it painfully obvious what we're looking at. Did you ever get this figured out? If so, please come back and post your result as an answer, then give yourself a check mark so others know this has been solved (self-answers are perfectly acceptable and expected).

Comment: Voting to close, unfortunately. OP hasn't been back.

Answer (score -1):

Honestly, from the questions you're asking and, the work you've described, I think you should hire an electrician.

If you're running 120 from one location to another, you don't need a sub-panel. Your 220/240 is two-phase. It is split in your service panel, left side breakers are one phase 120/110, and the right is the second phase. You get 220 from a panel by using a 2-gang breaker and providing two legs of 110 on the same phase. Wire rating is as follows:

- 15A - 14 ga.
- 20A - 12 ga.
- 30A - 10 ga.
- 40A - 8 ga.
- 55A - 6 ga.

Comment: 1 - Even with just 120, sometimes a subpanel **is** the best solution; 2 - It isn't usually left/right, the alternate legs/phases are usually in pairs on each side

Comment: Not in the U.S. The legs split coming into the main panel.

Comment: The legs split. But then the buses weave around. That's how you end up with pairs of breakers for 240V.

Comment: If you are determined to do this yourself, educate yourself. But the Black & Decker book "The Complete Guide to Wiring." https://www.amazon.com/Black-Decker-Complete-Wiring-Updated/dp/0760353573